# Create Link for visiting site as registered user. But this link will have expire date(example 3 days)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, development-environment

I have created a web site. Registered users can do every thing. But I want to give permission registered users to create link  which allow unregistered users browse as registered user. But this link will have expire date. When unregisterd user clicks this link he /she can browse in the web site.

I am creating this site in ASP MVC 4.0

Can you help me for formalizing the structure?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have `Link` model:

```
public class Link
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

When user create link, set current date - `DateTime.Now` to `CreateDate` property. Using this method display link:

```
public static bool AllowToDisplay(DateTime linkDate)
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
    ts = DateTime.Now - linkDate;
    return ts.TotalDays > 3;
}
```

In view:

```
@if(AllowToDisplay(Model.CreateDate))
{
 <a href="Model.Title">Some text</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. When the user creates the link, capture the datetime and save it in a database. When ever the link is clicked, check if the age of the link is older than 3 days. If it is, deactivate the link and/or remove it. This is the easiest way.

Another way is to have a process running which will check and automatically disable the link after 3 days. This is usually more difficult to achieve though.